# Issue in Syncing the data between nodes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, upsert, reindex

We have 2 nodes node_a and node_b they both are on different servers where node_a is the main node here all the data needs to be where as node_b is a temp node where the data is being dump which needs to be synced to node_a currently we are using reindex method to sync the nodes, but any doing this we have seen there is data loss in the node_a.

For e.g.
Node_a has the following document

> {   "_index": "node_a",   "_type": "fields",   "_id":
>   "AW9_qd-qSvQmY6fL_xPQ",   "_score": 1,   "_source": {
>       "name": "BOB",
>       "age": 25,
>       "Location": "US",
>       "other": "123"   } }

And node_b has

> {
>       "_index": "node_b",
>       "_type": "fields",
>       "_id": "AW9_qd-qSvQmY6fL_xPQ",
>       "_score": 1,
>       "_source": {
>         "name": "BOB",
>         "gender": "male",
>       }   }

After reindexing the expected output we desire is

> {
>       "_index": "node_a",
>       "_type": "fields",
>       "_id": "AW9_qd-qSvQmY6fL_xPQ",
>       "_score": 1,
>       "_source": {
>         "name": "BOB",
>         "age": 25,
>         "Location": "US",
>         "other": "123",  "gender": "male",
>       }   }

Where only the missing data gets updates in the above case it's the gender, but instead the whole document is getting replaced.

Is there a way where I can achieve this by re-indexing method where only the missing data is updated int the document.

Comment: No, reindex doesnot support partial update. You will have to make a little script.

Comment: It should be possible to do this using logstash (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) but i thinck it would be more difficult than a simple script ;).

Comment: +1 for LeBigCat comment, if you want to do that you need to go with a script.
node_a don't lost data because of the reindex you have a problem with your application that overwrite some fields. You problem is not correctly formulated.